# What to do with an SO question that is migrated to SU and then closed as Off Topic?

Tags: support, status-completed, migration, specific-question

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/308181/how-to-write-a-clean-gmail-filter-for-svn-commits) was first migrated from Stack Overflow to Super User, and then closed as Off Topic. I don't care too much whether the solution to this particular problem comes in the form of a new Gmail feature, a Google API workaround, or some sort of browser hack that I haven't yet thought about - but I *do* think it is a reasonable question.

Sometimes the answer to a question is "there really is no good way to do that, yet," in which case IMO it would make sense to close the question with such a conclusion, rather than pretend that the question belongs somewhere else.

Is there a good place for my question at this point, or (lame possibility) do the users of SO and SU really have to wait for me to come up with a good answer to the question before I can ask it?

Comment: I've re-migrated it to webapps... ***with my mind.***

Comment: Thanks, if you're the one who [put it here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17337/how-to-write-a-clean-gmail-filter-for-svn-commits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question belongs on [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). Easy as that.

It shouldn't have been migrated to SuperUser in the first place, because it is as Off-Topic there as it is on StackOverflow.

Comment: I guess the problem is that when you vote to migrate a question, there's only a limited number of options of places to migrate to. Granted you don't want to overload the migration options, but it doesn't really matter that WebApps is the right place to move it to if WebApps isn't in the list of options: People will see that it's off topic, and vote for the next best thing that is in the list. So I guess the next question is: If I think a question should be moved to a site that isn't in the list, what should I do?

Comment: @Spudley: Feel free to open up a `Feature Request` for such a migration path.

Comment: @Bobby: Thanks for the clarification. Still being a fairly novice user of SO, I find the migration process to be somewhat opaque. At least now I know where to look for descriptions of the various sites.

Answer (score 4):

You can flag [the question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624852/how-to-write-a-clean-gmail-filter-for-svn-commits?noredirect=1) and ask for it to be re-migrated to [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). Moderators can clear migration history and make that happen for you.

The [SU version](https://superuser.com/questions/308181/how-to-write-a-clean-gmail-filter-for-svn-commits) of the question can/should be deleted, but that's more a matter of housekeeping and will likely happen in due course without you having to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Flag the questions on both sites.

The migration history on the original site can be cleared and the question re-migrated to the correct site.

The question on the wrong site can be simply deleted.